# How to re-render react component when a property changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint, spfx

so I have this react component, with a dropdown property (SPFx) which has 2 values, I need that when the dropdown is changed the react is re-rendered again, the dropdown defines the datasource from where the values will be retrieved.

Webpart.ts

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {  
  BaseClientSideWebPart,
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneDropdown
} from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";

import * as strings from 'AbstractfactoryWebPartStrings';
import Abstractfactory from './components/Abstractfactory';
import { IAbstractFactoryProps } from './components/IAbstractFactoryProps';
import { IAbstractfactoryWebPartProps } from "./IAbstractfactoryWebPartProps";




export default class AbstractfactoryWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IAbstractfactoryWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IAbstractFactoryProps > = React.createElement(
      Abstractfactory,
      {
        datasource: this.properties.datasource
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(propertyPath: string, oldValue: any, newValue: any): void {

    super.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(propertyPath, oldValue, newValue);
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneDropdown("datasource", {
                  label: "DataSource",
                  options: [
                      { key: "1", text: "Sharepoint"},
                      { key: "2", text: "JSON" }
                    ],
                  selectedKey: "1",
                  })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Component.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { IAbstractFactoryProps } from "./IAbstractFactoryProps";  
import { IAbstractFactoryState } from "./IAbstractFactoryState";  
import styles from './Abstractfactory.module.scss';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import DaoFactory from "./DaoFactory";  
import ICustomerDao from "./ICustomerDao";  
import DataSources from "./DatasourcesEnum";

export default class Abstractfactory extends React.Component<IAbstractFactoryProps, IAbstractFactoryState> {
  //Private instance of customerDao, please note it returns ICustomerDao, an Interface,
    //not a concrete type
    private customerDao: ICustomerDao;

    constructor(props: IAbstractFactoryProps, state: IAbstractFactoryState) {
      super(props);
      this.setInitialState();

      // We set the Dao depending on the selected data source
      this.setDaos(props.datasource);

      //Then we set the list of customers and note, we dont care if they come from Sharepoint
      //Rest API or anything else.
      this.state = {
        items: this.customerDao.listCustomers(),
      };
    }

    public render(): React.ReactElement<IAbstractFactoryProps> {
      return (
        <div className={ styles.abstractfactory }>
          <div className={ styles.container }>
            <div className={ styles.row }>
              <div className={ styles.column }>
              {this.state.items.map( i => (<div key={i.id}>{i.firstName}</div>))}
             </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

    public setInitialState(): void {
      this.state = {
        items: []
      };
    }

    private setDaos(datasource: string): void {
      const data: DataSources = datasource === "Sharepoint" ? DataSources.SharepointList : DataSources.JsonData;
      this.customerDao = DaoFactory.getDAOFactory(data).getCustomerDAO();

      //Now, its transparent for us a UI developers what datasource was selected
      //this.customerDao.
    }
}
```

State

```
import Customer from "./Customer";

export interface IAbstractFactoryState {  
    items?: Customer[];
  }
```

DaoFactory

```
import ICustomerDAO from "./ICustomerDAO";  

import DataSources from "./DatasourcesEnum";

abstract class DAOFactory {

    //For each entity we will need to implement getCustomerDAO, this will make it easily replaceable
    //when another datasource comes in
    public abstract getCustomerDAO(): ICustomerDAO;

    //Static method that receives a parameter depending on the datasource and will return the specifc 
    //factory
    public  static getDAOFactory(whichFactory: DataSources): DAOFactory {
        switch (whichFactory) {
          case DataSources.SharepointList:
            return new SharepointListDAOFactory();
          case DataSources.JsonData:
            return new JsonDAOFactory();
          default  :
            return null;
        }
      }
}

export default DAOFactory;
import SharepointListDAOFactory from "./SharepointListDAOFactory";  
import JsonDAOFactory from "./JsonDAOFactory";
```

JsonCustomerDao.ts

```
import ICustomerDao from "./ICustomerDao";  
import Customer from "./Customer";

  class JsonCustomerDAO implements ICustomerDao{
    public insertCustomer(): number {
        // implementation to be done by reader
        return 1;
    }

    public deleteCustomer(): boolean {
        // implementation to be done by reader
        return true;
    }

    public findCustomer(): Customer {
        // implementation to be done by reader
        return new Customer();
    }

    public updateCustomer(): boolean {
        // implementation to be done by reader
        return true;
    }

    public listCustomers(): Customer[] {
        // implementation to be done by reader
        let c1: Customer= new Customer();
        let c2: Customer= new Customer();
        c1.id="3";
        c1.firstName="Andrew";
        c1.lastName="Valencia";
        c2.id="4";
        c2.firstName="Charles";
        c2.lastName="Smith";


        let list: Array<Customer> = [c1, c2 ];
        return list;
    }
}

export default JsonCustomerDAO;
```

SharepointCustomerDao

```
import ICustomerDao from "./ICustomerDao";  
import Customer from "./Customer";

 class SharepointCustomerDao implements ICustomerDao {
    public insertCustomer(): number {
        // implementation to be done by reader
        return 1;
    }

    public deleteCustomer(): boolean {
         // implementation to be done by reader
        return true;
    }

    public findCustomer(): Customer {
         // implementation to be done by reader
        return new Customer();
    }

    public updateCustomer(): boolean {
         // implementation to be done by reader
        return true;
    }

    public listCustomers(): Customer[] {
         // implementation to be done by reader
        let c1: Customer = new Customer();
        c1.id="1";
        c1.firstName="Luis";
        c1.lastName="Valencia";
        let c2: Customer = new Customer();
        c2.id="2";
        c2.firstName="John";
        c2.lastName="Smith";
        let list: Array<Customer> = [c1, c2 ];
        return list;
    }
}

export default SharepointCustomerDao;
```

The first time its executed the values are rendered for the default datasource, but when the property changes, the UI is not changing with the new values.

I found that I can use this event to set the new props datasource value when the dropdown changes

```
 protected onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(propertyPath: string, oldValue: any, newValue: any): void {
    this.properties[this.properties.datasource] = newValue;


    this.render();

    super.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(propertyPath, oldValue, newValue);
  }
```

However the view is not re-rendered, can I use any of the react js events to re-render or re-set the status when a prop is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Reacts way to rerender a component on data change is to updates it's state.

For instance if you have a component `<Foo />` which contains a rendermethod to display it's state like

```
...
render() {
   return(
     <div>Hello {this.state.name}</div>
   )
}
...
```

The component will display Hello *and whetever is in the state.name*

A re-render happens everythime you update the state of the given component. So in your case if you get new items, you have to push them into the state. Once that happens the react class will trigger its render method and will use the current state to display new data.

For that to work you would need a custom method which is being called from outside or within your component.

For instance

```
...
foo(receivesSomething) {
   const items = this.state.items;
   items.push(receivesSomething);
   this.setState({items}); // once a setState is being executed in any component react will make a diff between the current DOM and the ShadowDOM, if something is different then it will trigger a re-render of the affected component
}
...
```

This article is quite nicely written http://lucybain.com/blog/2017/react-js-when-to-rerender/ and explains it a bit as well. I would recommend you to look into the lifecycle methods in general as well.

**update**

For instance like this.

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
      super();

      window.someFunction = payload => {
         // do whatever you want to do with the payload here
         this.setState({ items: payload });
      }

   }
}
```

**update2**

If your component is listening / receiving props you can use the `componentWillReceiveProps(newProps)` lifecycle method from react and update your component state within that

Comment: I understand that, the problem is that this is Sharepoint Framework, where I have a webpart with one dropdown property, and then  the webpart has the react component, there is an event called onPropertyPaneFieldChanged where I can put any logic, but how do I pass the new state there? or how do I trigger that the constructor is executed again, not sure if its clear my question.

Comment: As in JavaScript OOP programming a constructor is only called once as the class gets instanciated. Therefore it can't be called again. What you could do is, creating a method within the constructor, or compoentDidMount where you create a global method, that is accessible from the outside. e.g. window.something = () => {}; and withing that method you receive whatever update happens and then add the setState there

Comment: a method within the constructor? not sure if I underfstood that.

Comment: Updated my Answer. Sorry im at work, have to cut it short sometimes ^^

Comment: not sure if it will work Property 'someFunction' does not exist on type 'Window'.

Comment: Why not? The Window is the global object of the Browser-enviroment. You can attach as many keys as you want to it. https://jsfiddle.net/smajn8L4/

Comment: yes I know that but its not recognized by the compiler I guess, probably because is not a 100% react project, its sharepoint framework react

Comment: Yes you can use the componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) method to listen to prop changes - try that out

Comment: Ok ill put it in my answer :)